# frequent gnome shell crashes at boot

Tags: gnome-shell, crash

Ubuntu 18.04.3
gnome-shell 3.28.4
x11 (X.Org 1.19.6)

I have struggled with this for many months, but recently it is getting much worse.

When I start up the computer, the process of booting frequently freezes with a black screen.  Sometimes I end up with a desktop showing no desktop icons.  Sometimes I am kicked back to the screen where I have to again select my user and reenter my password.  In  either case, I end up with a log file of the crash located in /var/crash.  It usually runs from 50 MB to over 200 MB.  But, I am not a technical person, I don't know how to interpret the contents of that file.  I can obviously see that it says that gnome-shell crashed, but I already knew that.

As I wrote above, I am not a technical person.  I don't know how to go about tracking down the problem, what tools to use to do that, etc.

I know there are a lot of gnome-shell crashing questions here and on the internet in general.  But, I often do not understand what is being discussed, or, I can tell that the problem being discussed is different from mine.

I would include information here to show the problem, but I don't even know what information any of you would want to see.

For the my level of expertise, what I am asking is this:

1)  How do I diagnose what the problem is?

2)  What tools/commands should I be running to help me figure out what is wrong?

3)  If Ask Ubuntu is not the proper place to be asking about this, any ideas on where I should be going to for help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a GNOME person, but if you've added extensions to your system, I would note what they are & their versions, and validate those versions are for 3.28 as in my experience this is a common reason for gnome crashes (which end your session & you're logged out). You could always de-activate/disable all and slowly add some back (with decent testing of each over a couple of sessions for each) until you've worked out which gnome extension (or two that don't play nice with each other) is your problem. You can then leave it out, or replace it with another extension.  My 2c

Comment: @guiverc , thanks, I know how to do that, I'll be trying that.

Comment: I agree with @guiverc. Edit your question and show us `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time experimenting with my installed gnome-shell extensions as suggested by @guiverc and @heynnema.  Their instincts were correct - I found two of the extensions that were causing the problem.  I do have the versions of the extensions installed that are stated to be proper for my version of gnome-shell (3.28.4), but they still are causing the problems I have seen.  Well - To be more precise, what I have seen the last few days is that when I disable those two extensions before shutting down the computer, the next time I start it up, I have had no problems.

My workaround for now until I get a new version of gnome-shell (once I upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04):  Before I shutdown the computer I disable those two extensions.